# What is the best place to store Autohosted-App settings and configurations?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, app

I have an autohosted app and I would like to store the application settings in a persistent way somewhere. From a web page inside the App the user should be able to edit and save such settings.
I saw it is possible to create a DB (an Azure SQL DB) along with the app or create a sharepoint hidden list. I can use both to store the settings. Are there other ways to do that? And what is the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Azure SQL DB and SharePoint Lists, the following option could be considered:

### SharePoint PropertyBag

Many of the important SharePoint client objects support a Properties property:

- [Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.aspx)
- [Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.Aspx)
- [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.Aspx)
- [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.Aspx)

This property returns a property bag object, which is a collection of key/value pairs. Each key must be uniquely named, each value is a string, and the key/value pair is stored with the owning object in the proper content database. The string value could be a serialized representation of a more complex object if that is required.

APIs: CSOM, REST

Example:

```
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var web = clientContext.get_web();
 var webProperties = web.get_allProperties();
 clientContext.load(webProperties);
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() { 
          var appSettings = webProperties.get_item('CustomAppSettings');
       },
       function(sender, args) {
          console.log('Error:' + args.get_message());
       }
);
```

### Pros

- **Native SharePoint functionality** Nothing needs to be added, configured, or activated, and cannot easily be eliminated.. The property bag is available as soon as the owning object is created and exists for the entire life of that object. This means that your application can interact with the property bag regardless of the type of environment; it only needs to be able to get a reference to the owning object
- **Scope** The property bag option is very granular because property bags are per-object

### Cons

- **Property bag availability** Certain key objects do not support a property bag.
- **No UI available**

Comment: Are there some pro/cons of choosing this option versus Azure SQL DB or SharePoint Lists?

Comment: The section about Pros/Cons has been added

Comment: I can vaguely remember some talk about "Configuration lists" before SharePoint 2013 beta was released, although I can't find anything about this now?